# Debugging an app with computed environment variables in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables, vscode-debugger

Consider an app which, in [12-factor style](https://12factor.net/config), receives its config in the form of a JSON document provided as an environment variable. The config contains secrets, so it is never stored on disk; instead, it is computed on the fly before starting the app, using something like [sops](https://github.com/mozilla/sops) or [nunjucks](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks).

I am trying to debug such an app in VS Code. Is there any way to run some arbitrary script before launch and provide its output to the app as an environment variable?

I will accept answers for any language or runtime, but an approach that works with package.json scripts or Node.js binaries (e.g. Jest, Playwright) would be most helpful for me.

Comment: can you give examples of commands to get JSON, JSON content and how you want it in an env variable (use dummy secrets)

Comment: what does a template engine (nunjucks) to do with your question